# Unit testing for modern PCL, compatible with .NET Core

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, xunit.net, .net-core

I use Class Library (Portable) project template in Visual Studio to produce modern PCL, compatible with .NET Core. Unfortunately, I unable to run unit tests for PCL with neither NUnit nor XUnit:

1. First of all, I can't create Class Library (Package) or Console Application (Package) for unit testing project. VS 2015 currently does not allow to reference modern PCL from these types of project: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1099
   Therefore, I should use Class Library (Portable) project for unit testing project.
2. That's why I can not follow articles http://www.alteridem.net/2015/11/04/testing-net-core-using-nunit-3/ (for NUnit) and https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html (for xUnit). Both articles use Class Library (Package) and Console Application (Package) projects.
3. I can't install 'xunit' package to Class Library (Portable) project. It fails with that error: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/587
4. I can successfully build Class Library (Portable) project with NUnit 3. But currently there are no test runner that can run NUnit 3 tests for .NET Core. Not sure if latest version of Resharper supports that - in any case Resharper is not an option for me.

It looks that I need to wait either for bug fixes in modern PCL support or for .NET Core-compatible NUnit 3 test runner. Could you recommend any workaround?

Comment: Based on the issue you link to, the problem is only if the PCL targets 4.6. The PCL version of NUnit targets PCL 4.5 which is probably why my post about [Testing .NET Core using NUnit](http://www.alteridem.net/2015/11/04/testing-net-core-using-nunit-3/) works. You do not say what the code under test targets. Does it need to target 4.6?

I am guessing from your post that your unit test assembly is PCL targeting 4.6 and .NET Core. Based on this, I assume that the code under test is the same. Can you retarget your PCL projects to be 4.5 + .NET Core + Windows Universal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The NUnit team and I have released full .NET Core support, including running tests within Visual Studio's Test Explorer. See [NUnit 3 Tests for .NET Core RC2 and ASP.NET Core RC2](http://www.alteridem.net/2016/06/18/nunit-3-testing-net-core-rc2/) for more info.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that! Visual Studio improved support for referencing .NET Standard portable projects too.